# Using UPCASE or Regexp in Array Column on Postgres

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-postgresql

I am trying to query a Postgres Array Column disregarding case and perhaps even disregarding spaces as well.

```
SELECT "cats".* FROM "cats" WHERE ('CATS - PERSA' = ANY(UPCASE(cat_types))) ORDER BY "cats"."id" ASC LIMIT 1;
```

But I get this error:

```
You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

AS a bonus I would like to also be able to do a regexp where the search ignores spaces in values on the cat_types column.

I am using Ruby on Rails to do this.

```
cat_type.upcase.delete(' ')
Cats.where("'#{cat_type}' = ANY(cat_types)").first
```

The query works just using ANY but I want to be able to disregard spaces and upcase the values in cat_types so that it has more chances of matching. Ilike could also be a possibility.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `'CATS - PERSA' ~* ANY(cat_types)`? It will do case-insensitive regexp mach.

Comment: I had not tried that, did not even know it existed, that worked and it disregarded the case. Thanks.It would be nice to disregard spaces as well.

Comment: You may want to read [`this`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html) page. It could be usefull to get some time and read the full manual - it has alot of nice things you do not know about.

Comment: I don't know if this will work with the ANY clause, but try something like: ANY(cat_types) ~* 'CAT\s*-\s*PERSA'

Comment: You report problems with *type casts* and *still* keep the actual data types from us? Best provide the table definition (what you get with `\d tbl` in `psql`) .

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT c.*
FROM   cats c, unnest(c.cat_types) AS cat_type
WHERE  upper(translate(cat_type, ' ', '')) = 'CATS-PERSA'
ORDER  BY id
LIMIT  1;
```

- The Postgres function is [`upper()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL), not `upcase()`.
- `cat_types` seems to be an array, assuming type `text[]`. I [`unnest()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unnest) to treat array elements individually. This cannot be done with `ANY`, which is only good for simple comparison.
- I use an implicit [`LATERAL JOIN`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lateral) here, requires Postgres **9.3+**.
- If multiple array elements match, you get the row multiple times here. Hence the `DISTINCT`.

About pattern-matching in Postgres:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)